# Leibniz test proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I would like to show following:

If $a_n$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ with $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \dots$ and $a_n \to 0$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k a_k$ converges.

I want to do the proof by showing the partial sums $s_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. My proof is the following, please can you tell me if it is correct:

Let $N<n<m$. Since $a_n$ is monotone decreasing eventually all $a_n$ will have the same sign. We may therefore assume that all $a_n$ have the same sign. We will show the claim assuming all $a_n$ are $\ge 0$. The case $a_n \le 0$ is similar.

By triangle inequality,  $|s_m-s_n| \le |s_n - s_{N-1}| + |s_m - s_{N-1}| $. If $n$ and $N$ are even then
$$\begin{aligned} 
|s_n - s_{N-1}| &= |\sum_{k=N}^{n} (-1)^k a_k| \\
&= |a_N - a_{N+1} + a_{N+2}- a_{N + 3 } + a_{N+4} \dots - a_{n-1} + a_n| \\
&\stackrel{\ast}{\le} |(a_N - a_{N+1}) + (a_{N+1} -a_{N+2}) + (a_{N+2}- a_{N + 3 }) + (a_{N+3} -a_{N+4})  \dots - a_{n-1} + a_n | \\
&\le |a_N + a_n| \\
&\le |a_N| + |a_n| \le 2 |a_N|
\end{aligned}$$

where in $\ast$ the assumption that $a_n \ge 0$ is needed.

Similarly, if $n$ is odd then $|s_n - s_{N-1}| \le |a_N - a_n| \le |a_N| + |a_n|$. Let $N$ be even and such that $a_N < {\varepsilon \over 4}$ then for $m,n > N$ it follows that $|s_n-s_m| \le 4|a_N|< \varepsilon$.

Comment: Sir, can u pls explain me following>?
Here in (*) Step, $a_{N+2} \leq a_{N+1}, a_{N+3} \leq a_{N+2} \implies -a_{N+3} \geq a_{N+2} $ But how $a_{N+2}-a_{N+3} \leq a_{N+1}-a_{N+2} $ holds? Kindly elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments:

1. When $n$ is even, the bound is simply $a_N$.
2. After you group the pairs, no absolute values are needed (everything is positive).
3. There is no case $a_n\leq0$. Your hypotheses imply that if $a_n\leq0$ for some $n$, then $a_{n+k}=0$ for all $k$. In other words, $a_n\geq0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you! Otherwise is correct?

Comment: Yep.${\ \ \ \ }$